# Compilation error when I am trying to import provideClientHydration

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I am trying to import the `provideClientHydration` from `@angular/platform-browser`,but it is showing compilation error though I had enabled the `Angular-ssr` dependencies in my application.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least `@angular/core` 16.0.0 to enable client hydration